# How do I scale the height of a div the same way that a div with an image does?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs that are floated next to each other. In one of the divs I have an image that scales (both it´s height and width) when I decrease the size of the browser window. In the other div I have some other content, but this is only being scaled in width when I decrease the size of the browser window. I want both of the divs to have the same height at all times, even when they are being scaled. Is this possible?

If you want a live preview, please check out this link: 
http://jjberg.com/cipher/index.html

I know part of the problem is that I´ve actually set a height of 500px to the cipherSide div. This is because so far I haven´t been able to make the height of this div closer to the height of the pinupSide div in any other way.

I tried to copy the declarations from the pinupSide and pinUpGirl to the cipherSide and verticalAlign divs, but to no avail. This only pushed the content in the cipherSide div all the way to the top.

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="pinupSide">
    <img class="pinUpGirl" src="images/pin_up_edited_x2.png" alt="Pin up girl">
  </div>

  <div class="cipherSide">
    <div class="verticalAlign">
      <h1> Dirty Diana </h1>
      <p>Dirty Diana wants to send dirty love messages to her husband, but she does not want Big Brother to know about it. Try out the tool I made for her!</p>
      <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Insert the text you want to cipher or decipher here!" required></textarea>
      <button id="cipherIT">Cipher It!</button>
      <button id="deCipher">Decipher!</button>
      <p id="newOne"></p>
    </div><!-- verticalAlign -->
  </div><!-- cipherSide -->

</div><!-- container -->
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 992px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}
.pinupSide {
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.pinUpGirl {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.cipherSide {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}
.verticalAlign {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

I want both of the divs to have the same height at all times, no matter how I´m scaling the width of the browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you code I assume you want the two elements to have the same height but also the same width at all time. I also assume you want the image to be as big as possible inside the left element without being distorted. Is that right?

If you can use CSS Grid, you can achieve that layout with a grid made up of two columns of each `1fr`, which represent one fraction of the available space. See the following code:

The `<img>` element has its `width` set to `100%` so that it is as big as possible inside its parent element, and its parent element has the `font-size` set to `0` to remove an unwanted space below the image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #3ff4fe;
}

.container {
  max-width: 992px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.image {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 0;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://jjberg.com/cipher/images/pin_up_edited_x2.png" alt="Pin up girl">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Does this help?

Comment: You are right about your assumptions Auguste. I should have specified this more clearly. Your answer definitely helps! I have not learned about the CSS grid yet, so I will look into it for sure. Only thing I struggle with now is to vertically center align the content in the "text" div. But that is another question, and I will learn more about CSS grid to tackle that.

Answer (score 1):

I second the use of grid like Auguste said. You could also use flex-box instead of floats and absolute positioning. Here is one possible implementation.

You'll probably have to play with `object-fit` on the image. Or just set the background of the pinup side to be the image and change the positioning through background properties. Either way it should work out.

You can also set hard heights and widths if you want to and just you the flex-box for positioning.

If you run the code snippet be sure to view it full screen because it uses view-port units for the height of the container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pinupSide,
.cipherSide {
  flex: 1 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pinupSide {
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.pinUpGirl {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}

.cipherSide {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)
}

.heading-group {
  background: rgba(241, 196, 15, 1);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.button-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="pinupSide">
    <img class="pinUpGirl" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530650819615-f14c8a735dd8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" alt="Pin up girl">
  </div>

  <div class="cipherSide">
    <div class="heading-group">
      <h1> Dirty Diana </h1>
      <p>Dirty Diana wants to send dirty love messages to her husband, but she does not want Big Brother to know about it. Try out the tool I made for her!</p>
    </div>
    <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Insert the text you want to cipher or decipher here!" required></textarea>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button id="cipherIT">Cipher It!</button>
      <button id="deCipher">Decipher!</button>
    </div>
    <p id="newOne"></p>
  </div><!-- cipherSide -->

</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing gitMasi. I now see that the way I defined my question could have caused some confusion. Your solution is also correct, but the reason I accepted the answer from Auguste is because I like the way the divs are scaling up and down together in that solution. In your solution the divs stay the same all the time, but the content inside scales. But I totally see why you interpreted my question like that the way I posed it. I will remember to be more clear next time around.